# Failure distribution for florescent lights. Is the failure per unit time constant or does it increase with bulb age?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, statistics, electrical-engineering

what is the distribution for the statistic:' time to failure'   for florescent light bulbs.  does the probability  of failure per unit time stay fixed as the bulb ages, or does does it increase.

Comment: The current version of the question doesn't seem be the same as what the OP was asking. (Though I understand the impulse to try to edit it so it can be reopened.)

Answer (score 1):

Electronic parts usually have a high(er) probability of failure at turn-on, which then decreases, and the slowly increases (per surviving unit)...but that is a very general statement that is not applicable in lots of cases.

In space-borne products, parts go through burn-in to weed out the failures, and then you put the most reliable part into space.

The field is called reliability engineering (not physics), and uses Weibull Analysis. If you look at the Weibull probability distribution: it can have a lot of different shapes.